# How can I determine the container template type of an instantiated container template in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, traits

I need collection_traits with which I can do something like

```
typename collection_traits<std::vector<int>>::template type<double> double_vector;
```

Now double_vector is of type `std::vector<double>`.

So what I want is to get the same container, but with different value type.

Is this even possible?

Comment: *Now double_vector is of type std::vector* ??? How did you conclude that?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do. Get the collection of the same type, but with different value_type? Plus there's no context in which you want to use this which makes giving any reasonable answer hard.

Comment: What do you expect to do for `std::set`? `std::map`? What if there are custom comparators?

Comment: @Barry he probably wants to use this collection_traits for vectors, lists, stacks, queues and deques.

Comment: This can probably be done for [**SequenceContainers**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/SequenceContainer) without too much hassle, using some template magic.

Comment: @АндрейБеньковский It is up to the OP to determine what it is the OP wants to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Variadic template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template) will help you https://ideone.com/lbS2W3

```
using namespace std;

template<typename... T>
struct collection_traits { using template_type = void; };

template<template<typename...> class C, typename... Args>
struct collection_traits<C<Args...> > {
  template<typename... Subst>
  using template_type = C<Subst...>;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  collection_traits<vector<int>>::template_type<double> t;

  cout << typeid(t).name() << endl;

  t.push_back(123.5);
  cout << t.front() << endl;

}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I almost got there, but the alias template was missing in my attempts. Great. I get it.